# Jailbroken iPhone stuck on black screen after erasing all content?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, charging

Yesterday, I decided to restore my iphone to factory default setting . So I format my iphone through setting menu (but the battery was low) . Then i kept my phone on charge but nothing happen. I also bought a new charger and cable but my iphone won't charge. I have been trying to reset it (holding power and home button) and I have tried putting it in safe mode but no luck .

Nothing is happening , even after charging for 2-3 hours . No logos , no indications , no buttons etc.

Comment: when you plug your iPhone do you see the charging screen ? when it's not charging and you push the power button do you see anything on the screen?

Comment: Nope everything is black. when I plug my iphone it shows nothing . I also tried pushing power button ..nothing works .

Comment: If you have a mac connect your iPhone through usb and run `system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep iPhone` or  just `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` and check if there is some information about your iPhone, if nothing is showing then maybe the battery is dead, try replacing it this all I can think about.

Comment: Google DFU mode and follow the instructions, you will need iTunes.

Comment: I don't have mac.

Comment: I tried DFU mode but nothing happens .

Comment: I am having the same problem today, any fixes yet?

Answer (score -3):

is your pc/laptop recognize the iphone (after connect to pc)?. try connect usb cable with pressed home key.

Comment: not recognised.